# grep for a string followed by matching two or three chars

Tags: regex, linux, string, unix, grep

Given an input file:

```
exception Error 1
exception Error 2
warning Error 123 (ignore)
warning Error 123 (ignore)
exception Error 3
```

I want to grep only lines which end with only Error 1 or Error 2, but not those which end with ignore. I don't want to use two grep commands by piping the output; I want to use only single grep command.

I tried something like `grep "Error.." file` though I am restricting it to two chars it still outputs ignore strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use end anchor in regex:

```
grep -E 'Error [12]$' file
exception Error 1
exception Error 2
```

or **word boundary**:

```
grep -E 'Error [12]\b' file
exception Error 1
exception Error 2
```